# Prevent mouse from waking computer from sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, mouse, sleep

Mouse seems to wake my computer from sleeping at the smallest touch, this is totally useless, but found no way to turn it off.

I did disable the 'Allow device to wake computer..' under Device Manager > Mouse settings.

Windows 10 and mouse is a Logitech M220.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following method, check if it works correctly.

1: Open `Command Prompt` with Run as administrator
2: type `powercfg \DEVICEDISABLEWAKE "devicename"` and press Enter
3: `Restart` the computer

Note: Use your device name you want to disable within quotes instead of `devicename`, in my example my device name is `HID-compliant mouse`, you can find your device name from Device Properties > Hardware > Devices > Name

Answer (score 0):

I might be very late to answer, but I had the same problem with my wireless mouse recently, and disabling the setting above didn't resolve the problem.

Apparently, Windows recognizes my wireless mouse both as a "mouse" and a "**keyboard**" device. So I just had to find the imposter keyboard and disable the "wake computer" setting for that device. That resolved the issue for me.

[image: imposter-keyboard]